# Setting locale in Ubuntu 12.04 (openvz)

Tags: ubuntu, openvz, environment-variables, utf-8, localization

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 as virtual openVZ guest.
The defined locale for LC_* in basic setup is POSIX.

I'd like to change this to en_US.UTF-8.
So I installed language_pack_en_base and language_pack_en, ran dpkg-reconfigure locales and added the following lines to /etc/environment and /etc/default/locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=C
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

But after restarting the virtual machine the output of locale is:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

What else can I do to set en_US.UTF-8 as locale for this server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case when logging in with ssh none of the usual default locale or environment variable settings seemed to work. It was because I had disabled PAM session control in sshd configuration.

Make sure you have set

```
UsePAM yes
```

in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file

Answer (score 1):

There is a file `/etc/default/locale` for persistent setting of system locales. Alternatively, you can use `update-locale` command instead of direct editing of that file.

More about locale settings can be found on [Ubuntu community help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale).

Comment: I already tried update-locale and as I wrote I added the posted configuration to /etc/default/locale.

Comment: Do you have it in /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local ? There should be a line en_US.UTF-8. Then, run reconfigure again.

Comment: Yes, I have. Regenerating the locales had no effect. If I export the variables on command line it takes effect. But after rebooting it always is POSIX